# Разные поведения <div> по нажатию одной кнопки

Tags: jquery

Как с помощью jquery по нажатию кнопки один раз вызвать первое событие, при последующих нажатиях на эту же кнопку новое событие?
Есть такой код

```
$('.btn').one('click',function(){
    $('.col').hide();
    $('.col').css('padding', '15');
    $('.col').css('border-bottom', '2px solid #00b7f4');
    $('.col').slideDown(900);
});



  $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.col').slideUp(150);
    $('.col').css('padding', '15');
    $('.col').css('border-bottom', '2px solid #00b7f4');
    $('.col').slideDown(150);
```

});

Comment: Проблема в том, что при первом нажатии происходят оба события.

Comment: используйте флаг\счетчик.

Comment: ну дак и навешайте второй обработчик, внутри первого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение от @teran:

```js
function first() {
  console.log("first");
  $(this).off("click").on("click", second);
}

function second() {
  console.log("second");
  $(this).off("click").on("click", first);
}

$('.btn').on('click', first);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

Решение от @Qwerty_Wasd:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).data("flag")) {
    console.log("second");
    $(this).data("flag", "");
  } else {
    console.log("first");
    $(this).data("flag", "1");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```